# How to check if wget has completed download successfully?

Tags: wget

I have a small bash script that download files from another server, sometimes download gets interrupted. How can I check if wget has completed download successfully?

Comment: Check out this post, you should use the return value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717303/checking-wgets-return-value-if

Answer (score 0):

if it gets interrupted then it may have part of the file ?

If it has part of the file - how would you know if the file is the full file or not depends on two different checks.

Either you have the actual file maybe from another attempt of the same script executed then the files compared - you could compare the files using md5 to ensure their identical.

The other less accurate method could be done over 1 attempt and you could do a du -sk on the file and if its above a certain size it passes - this by no way can ensure if file is 100% there if cut off 99%

but you could also look into wget -c which resumes downloads ---

so maybe run it twice with this option:

```
wget --help 2>&1 |grep "\-\-continue"
  -c,  --continue                resume getting a partially-downloaded file.
```

if it is a web server you are in control of you could install:
[https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache::OpenIndex](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache%3a%3aOpenIndex)

I think this displays the md5 sum of the directoryindex so you can then parse this and compare to local md5 sum of your downloaded file - if a miss match run wget -c