# Wget's return value always get 0

Tags: linux, bash, centos, wget

I'm trying to use the following accepted answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717303/checking-wgets-return-value-if),
for example doing :

```
wget_output=$(wget -q google.com)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "not zero"
else
    echo "zero"
fi
```

But I always get the `$?` value to be `0`, no matter if site exists/responsive or not. 
Please advise

Comment: @ryekayo That wouldn't make sense, it's the exit code you'd want to check, not the textual output of wget.

Comment: your script works for me.

Comment: What is your `wget` version? Apparently `wget` had exit status issues prior to 1.12.

Comment: @AlanAu: I have 1.12 built on linux gnu

Comment: Running on centos. if it is matter

Comment: You'll probably need to `yum update`

Comment: Please advice which command to launch, pretty new to it

Answer (score 1):

Try narrowing the problem down and testing the return value of the command directly with the `if`:

```
if wget http://www.google.com/badname
then echo 'true'
else echo 'not true'
fi

if wget http://www.google.com/index.html
then echo 'true'
else echo 'not true'
fi
```

Comment: if I run my script with `#!/bin/bash`, does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
if wget -q google.com; then
```

And seems to work now, if the site exists, then it's not 0 and the condition takes place, else it is empty and the condition doesn't take place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 URL="https://google.nl"

 wget $URL --no-check-certificate -o /dev/null

 if [ $? == 8 ]; then
    echo "The site does'nt exist"
 fi
```