# wget on failure returns last command executed code unknown

Tags: bash, wget, mktemp

Here is a small bash code which initially creates a temporary file `tmpfile` using `mktemp` followed by a `wget` operation on success or failure removes the temporary file created.

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
tmpfile="$(mktemp)"
wget -q $1 -O /tmp/temp.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "wget success"
    rm "${tmpfile}"
else
    echo "wget fail" 
    rm "${tmpfile}"
fi
```

When a right url is passed to the script, `wget` on success checks the return value of last command using `$?` and deletes the temporary file as expected.

```
root@box:/# ./temp.sh www.google.com
++ mktemp
+ tmpkeyfile=/tmp/tmp.83uGY1NH5B
+ wget -q www.google.com -O /tmp/temp.txt
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'wget success' 
wget success
+ rm /tmp/tmp.83uGY1NH5B
```

However if a url which result `wget` a unsuccessful such as 404-not found etc., I assume last executed `wget` should fail against `if` check and delete temporary file in `else` block. This isn't happening as `wget` just returns without any last return value as shown below. This indeed doesn't delete the temporary file when ever call to `wget` fails.

```
root@box:/# ./temp.sh www.googlegoogle.com
++ mktemp
+ tmpkeyfile=/tmp/tmp.pSL7hKyAlz
+ wget -q www.googlegoogle.com -O /tmp/temp.txt
root@box:/#
```

May I know how to capture every return failure code of `wget` by any means.

Comment: The `-e` in your shebang line tells bash to exit the script if any command returns a nonzero exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question:

> May I know how to capture every return failure code of wget by any
>   means.

It should response every return http status code:

```
wget --server-response http://googlegoogle/nx.file 2>&1 | awk '/^  HTTP/{print $2}'
```

**EDIT**:
I have tried your code, and it works fine

```
bash -x ./abc.sh www.googlegoogle.com
++ mktemp
+ tmpfile=/tmp/tmp.pwa08vGnjo
+ wget -q www.googlegoogle.com -O /tmp/temp.txt
+ '[' 4 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo 'wget fail'
wget fail
+ rm /tmp/tmp.pwa08vGnjo
```

This is the list of exit codes for wget:

```
0       No problems occurred
1       Generic error code
2       Parse error — for instance, when parsing command-line options, the .wgetrc or .netrc…
3       File I/O error
4       Network failure
5       SSL verification failure
6       Username/password authentication failure
7       Protocol errors
8       Server issued an error response
```

Check this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717303/checking-wgets-return-value-if)

Comment: With this I have to change my code in order to check all the http status codes available and take a call which is complex.